# Laptop power cord splicing, Red Vs Blue

Tags: laptop, colors, repair

### Components specs

**Laptop**

Brand: Toshiba

**Original cord**

Brand: Natno (replacement AC adapter)
Model: SK90195231
Input: 100-240V--1.3A
**Output: 19.5V–––2.31A**
Wire Colors: black,white,**brown/red**

**New HP Cord**

Brand: Hp AC Adapter
Regulatory Model: PPP009C
HP Part #: 677774-002
Input: 100-240V--1.7A 50-60Hz
**Output: 19.5V–––3.33A 65W**
Wire colors: black,white, **blue**

### My problem

My Toshiba laptop power cord finally gave out and I cant afford a new cord at the moment. So I found a random HP power cord I had have no other use for. The DC plug is a different size than what I need for my laptop. So I cut the end piece off of the HP cord so that I could simply rewire the compatible DC plug onto it. The original cord is made of black/white/ & **RED** wires. The hp cord is made of black/white/ & **BLUE** wires. So after doing extensive research on repairing a laptop charger correctly, I found nothing answering the question if these are compatible.

### Question

Can I rewire these two pieces together as though they were the same colors?

- Black-black
- white-white
- red-blue

### ☆☆**EDITED**☆☆

☆ Sorry for the confusion n yes, i meant to use "dc" instead of "ac" in my question/ description.

☆ i will attach photos to try n give a visual and better understanding of my complication & supplement where i may be lacking some other correct terminologies or overlooked details...

### **im am so greatful for each any every one of you taking the time out of your days to give me advice and/or attempt to help me understand and solve this problem!!!**

Comment: What do the plugs look like? Did you mean the DC plugs on the laptop side, or the AC plugs on the mains side? (Definitely won't be AC on the laptop side...)

Comment: do not make any assumptions ... wire colors could be any which way ... use an ohmmeter to determine which color connects to which connector pin

Comment: Why did you talk about **ac** plug?  Is this where you want to plug the cable into your laptop?  That should be DC.

Comment: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Wiring-for-Power-adapter/td-p/746693 has some interesting observations.   It is not certain that what you are doing will work as one of the pins is likely either a temperature sensor or otherwise talking betwen the PSU and laptop - so there is more then just the voltage to worry about.

Comment: Per https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23Y2MvHkmao - on the HP - Blue is center tip (ie sensor pin), Black is outside pin - which is ground, white is V+ which is the inside part of the outer connector.    Grab a multimeter and double check your Toshiba voltages - my guess is black will be ground, white will be V+.   I would not use the charger long term, but I'd try it without connecting red to blue and if that works leave it at that (and I assume you would get messages about it being a non HP certifed supply and possibly limiting the current)...

Comment: The confusion is that the round ("barrel") connector is for 19.5 volts **DC** (VDC), and you discuss the **AC** (mains) plug that goes into a wall outlet, perhaps 120 VAC (Americas) or 240 VAC (e.g., Europe). Please edit your question.

Comment: Ok, silly question - before you cut anything apart - did you try plugging in the 'new' charger to see if it worked? If its the same voltage and barrel type, it might just work, also how are you actually planning on splicing the cables?